# Jquery popup model content scroll down issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a model popup to the help of jquery and CSS. I need help that is- in my model body content is large since I want  a button which name would be `NEXT` when user click `Next` the body content would be scroll down at every button click and after end of content when no any text for scroll button changed from `Next` to `Done` and when I click `Done` page will redirect.

In this case the outside frame of model would be fix , I means no body can scroll the model only public can scroll model body if scroll down to end button changed to `Done`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4d7j5za/9/)

```js
$(function() {

  var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

  $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    //$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#' + modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
  });


  $(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
    $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(".modal-overlay").remove();
    });

  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".modal-box").css({
      top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
      left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
    });
  });

  $(window).resize();

});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "roboto", helvetica;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #444;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1.75em 0 0;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.v-center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.v-center>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 3vmin;
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn-small {
  padding: .75em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 98%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

@media (min-width: 32em) {
  .modal-box {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.modal-box header,
.modal-box .modal-header {
  padding: 1.25em 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.modal-box header h3,
.modal-box header h4,
.modal-box .modal-header h3,
.modal-box .modal-header h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-box .modal-body {
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
}

.modal-box footer,
.modal-box .modal-footer {
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  text-align: right;
}

.modal-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}

a.close {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
}

a.close:hover {
  color: #222;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<section class="v-center">
  <div>
    <h2>Super Simple Modal Popups Demo</h2>
    <br/>
    <a class="js-open-modal btn" href="#" data-modal-id="popup1"> Pop Up One</a> </div>
</section>
<div id="popup1" class="modal-box">
  <header> <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>Pop Up One</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo at felis vitae facilisis. Cras volutpat fringilla nunc vitae hendrerit. Donec porta id augue quis sodales. Sed sit amet metus ornare, mattis sem at, dignissim arcu. Cras rhoncus ornare
      mollis. Ut tempor augue mi, sed luctus neque luctus non. Vestibulum mollis tristique blandit. Aenean condimentum in leo ac feugiat. Sed posuere, est at eleifend suscipit, erat ante pretium turpis, eget semper ex risus nec dolor. Etiam pellentesque
      nulla neque, ut ullamcorper purus facilisis at. Nam imperdiet arcu felis, eu placerat risus dapibus sit amet. Praesent at justo at lectus scelerisque mollis. Mauris molestie mattis tellus ut facilisis. Sed vel ligula ornare, posuere velit ornare,
      consectetur erat.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo at felis vitae facilisis. Cras volutpat fringilla nunc vitae hendrerit. Donec porta id augue quis sodales. Sed sit amet metus ornare, mattis sem at, dignissim arcu. Cras rhoncus ornare
      mollis. Ut tempor augue mi, sed luctus neque luctus non. Vestibulum mollis tristique blandit. Aenean condimentum in leo ac feugiat. Sed posuere, est at eleifend suscipit, erat ante pretium turpis, eget semper ex risus nec dolor. Etiam pellentesque
      nulla neque, ut ullamcorper purus facilisis at. Nam imperdiet arcu felis, eu placerat risus dapibus sit amet. Praesent at justo at lectus scelerisque mollis. Mauris molestie mattis tellus ut facilisis. Sed vel ligula ornare, posuere velit ornare,
      consectetur erat.</p>

  </div>
  <footer> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small js-modal-close">Next ></a> </footer>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include your code **inside** your post, don't link it from an external site. SO has it's own fiddle feature. Also, the included code should be a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Please I has been updated my question. I am new at stackoverflow that's why it happen. Sorry about That

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your snippet. I've used the jquery [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler to detect when the div has been scrolled to the bottom. I use the [`.scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function to scroll the div down on Next click.

I've also adjusted the height of the `modal-body` div on window resize such that a scroll bar appears if the content exceeds the window. This also requires the `overflow` css of the div to be set to `auto`.

```js
$(function() {

  var appendthis = ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

  function open(e) {
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(500, 0.7);
    $("#popup1").fadeIn();
  }

  function close() {
    $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(".modal-overlay").remove();
    });
  }

  $("header .js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
    close();
  });

  $("footer .js-modal-close").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "Done") {
      close();
    } else {
      var $modalBody = $(".modal-body");
      $modalBody.scrollTop($modalBody.scrollTop() + $modalBody.height());
    }
  });

  $(".modal-body").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      $("footer .js-modal-close").text("Done");
    } else {
      $("footer .js-modal-close").text("Next >");
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    // Get maximum height of modal body. Minimum 100.
    var maxHeight = Math.max($(window).height() - 220, 100);
    $(".modal-body").css("max-height", maxHeight);
    
    var heightPercentage = 0.25;
    $(".modal-body").height($(document).height() * heightPercentage);

    $(".modal-box").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2
    });

    $(".modal-body").scroll();
  })

  // show modal
  open();

  // adjust size
  $(window).resize();

});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "roboto", helvetica;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #444;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1.75em 0 0;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.v-center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.v-center>div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: -10%;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 3vmin;
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.btn-small {
  padding: .75em 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.modal-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 98%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  max-width:95%;
}

@media (min-width: 32em) {
  .modal-box {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.modal-box header,
.modal-box .modal-header {
  padding: 1.25em 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.modal-box header h3,
.modal-box header h4,
.modal-box .modal-header h3,
.modal-box .modal-header h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-box .modal-body {
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-box footer,
.modal-box .modal-footer {
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  text-align: right;
}

.modal-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}

a.close {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
}

a.close:hover {
  color: #222;
  -webkit-transition: color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 1s ease;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="popup1" class="modal-box">
  <header> <a href="#" class="js-modal-close close">×</a>
    <h3>Pop Up One</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo at felis vitae facilisis. Cras volutpat fringilla nunc vitae hendrerit. Donec porta id augue quis sodales. Sed sit amet metus ornare, mattis sem at, dignissim arcu. Cras rhoncus ornare
      mollis. Ut tempor augue mi, sed luctus neque luctus non. Vestibulum mollis tristique blandit. Aenean condimentum in leo ac feugiat. Sed posuere, est at eleifend suscipit, erat ante pretium turpis, eget semper ex risus nec dolor. Etiam pellentesque
      nulla neque, ut ullamcorper purus facilisis at. Nam imperdiet arcu felis, eu placerat risus dapibus sit amet. Praesent at justo at lectus scelerisque mollis. Mauris molestie mattis tellus ut facilisis. Sed vel ligula ornare, posuere velit ornare,
      consectetur erat.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut commodo at felis vitae facilisis. Cras volutpat fringilla nunc vitae hendrerit. Donec porta id augue quis sodales. Sed sit amet metus ornare, mattis sem at, dignissim arcu. Cras rhoncus ornare
      mollis. Ut tempor augue mi, sed luctus neque luctus non. Vestibulum mollis tristique blandit. Aenean condimentum in leo ac feugiat. Sed posuere, est at eleifend suscipit, erat ante pretium turpis, eget semper ex risus nec dolor. Etiam pellentesque
      nulla neque, ut ullamcorper purus facilisis at. Nam imperdiet arcu felis, eu placerat risus dapibus sit amet. Praesent at justo at lectus scelerisque mollis. Mauris molestie mattis tellus ut facilisis. Sed vel ligula ornare, posuere velit ornare,
      consectetur erat.</p>

  </div>
  <footer> <a href="#" class="btn btn-small js-modal-close">Next ></a> </footer>
</div>
```